# Why does this view only grab the first value, not all the list values?

Tags: python, django, list

I'm using checkbox, the problem is that I only can get the first value not all the values that I check, what I'm I doing wrong.

view.py

```
def solicitud_laboratorio(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    formulario = Solicitud_lab(request.POST)
    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.save()
        medicinas = []
    for i in range(len(request.POST.getlist('examen'))):
        data = {
            'nombre_examen': request.POST.getlist('examen')[i],
            'credencial_miembro': request.POST['laboratorio_credencial']
        }
        print data
        medicina = examenlab_form(data)

        if medicina.is_valid():
            medicina.save()
            medicinas.append(medicina)
            messages.success(request, 'Alta Exitosa!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        messages.success(request, 'Se presento un error al dar de alta')
else:
    medicinas = [examenlab_form()]
    formulario = Solicitud_lab()
return render_to_response('sol_laboratorio.html', {'medicinas': medicinas, 'formulario': formulario},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this is a part of the template, where I define the list

```
 <table style="width:20%; margin-left:70px " align="left" width="95%" cellspacing="0"     cellpadding="5" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#85D5EF">Hematologia</td>
    </tr>
{% for examen in medicinas %}
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="examen" value="BIOMETRIA HEMATICA"> Biometria Hematica</td>
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="examen" value="VEL DE SEDIMENTO GLOBULAR"> Vel De Sedimento Globular</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="examen" value="RETICULOCITOS"> Reticulocitos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="examen" value="COOMBS DIRECTO"> Coombs Directo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="examen" value="COOBS INDIRECTO"> Coombs Indirecto</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I can't tell if the indentation got messed up or not, but it looks like you return inside your for-loop, which would cause you to only use the first value. Also what is up with that for-loop, `request.POST.getlist` returns a list, why do you call it multiple times instead of just iterating over the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you exit the function with a `return` statement after processing only the first value:

```
for i in range(len(request.POST.getlist('examen'))):
    data = {
        'nombre_examen': request.POST.getlist('examen')[i],
        'credencial_miembro': request.POST['laboratorio_credencial']
    }
    print data
    medicina = examenlab_form(data)

    if medicina.is_valid():
        medicina.save()
        medicinas.append(medicina)
        messages.success(request, 'Alta Exitosa!')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('')
```

Move that `return` statement *out* of the loop. You should also just loop over the `.getlist()` call, no need to use induces here:

```
for exam in request.POST.getlist('examen'):
    data = {
        'nombre_examen': exam,
        'credencial_miembro': request.POST['laboratorio_credencial']
    }
    print data
    medicina = examenlab_form(data)

    if medicina.is_valid():
        medicina.save()
        medicinas.append(medicina)
        messages.success(request, 'Alta Exitosa!')

return HttpResponseRedirect('')
```